# How To Print IEnumerable List?

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn the IEnumerable interface and how can I print some data to the user.

This is the class Number:

```
public class Number
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> ReturnMyNumbers()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;

        foreach (int i in ReturnMyNumbers())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var PrintMeTheNumbers = Number.ReturnMyNumbers();
    Console.WriteLine(PrintMeTheNumbers);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Its not working

Comment: Are you sure this does not run infinitely?

Comment: Move the foreach in Main ( use PrintMeTheNumbers in the foreach). Also,start with easier C# constructs first (If ,loops,methods,etc)

Comment: @maccettura No, but it will throw a stack overflow pretty quickly :)

Comment: The `yield return` construct is a great tool, but when you use that, those calls are defining the collection itself, not operating on it.  However, that construct is not a good one for a beginner; start with declaring lists, then enumerating those.  As you work with collections that implement IEnumerable, you'll get used to its features, and eventually be ready for a custom iteration, like with yield return.

Answer (score 2):

Take a step back and look at what your code *actually* does:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ReturnMyNumbers()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;

    foreach (int i in ReturnMyNumbers())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Look at the `foreach` loop, its calling itself.  This is an example of *bad* recursion, there is no exit condition so it will just run until a [stack overflow exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown.

You have not really told us what your desired functionality is, but I am assuming you just want ReturnMyNumbers to give you `1,2,3` back?

Change your method to:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ReturnMyNumbers()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
```

Note that your code is pretty bad way of doing this, `yield` is a pretty nifty keyword but for what you are using it for its not really useful.  Why not just return an int array?

```
return new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Regardless of how you implement that method, you'll need to modify your `Main()` method to call `ReturnMyNumbers()` in the foreach like you were previously doing (albeit in the wrong place):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in Number.ReturnMyNumbers())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What is  IEnumerable interface ?

> IEnumerable is an interface that defines one method GetEnumerator
>   which returns an IEnumerator interface, this allows readonly access to
>   a collection then collection that implements IEnumerable can be used
>   with a for-each statement.

```
public class Customer : IEnumerable  {        
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()      {  throw new NotImplementedException(); }  }  

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections; 

namespace TestDomain
{
    class Program
    {
            public static void Main(String[] args)
            {

                IEnumerable<int> Values = from value inEnumerable.Range(1, 10) select value;

                foreach (int a in Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

             }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why an identity projection when you could just write `IEnumerable<int> values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);` ?